# Using pgfornament

Tags: pgfornament

I use `pgfornament` package to put decorations in the corner as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }

\begin{document}
\title{Magnificent title}
\maketitle 
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{New chapter}
\lipsum[5]
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Corner flowery]

But I would like to put these decorations from a particular page onwards only, say **from Chapter 1**. How can I modify the above code, *preferably without adding* new packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the code after `\mainmatter` (or any where from which point you want it)

```
.
.
\mainmatter
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }

\chapter{New chapter}
.
.
```

[image]

You can also define macros to put the ornaments for a number of pages:

```
 \newcommand{\beautify}{%
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }
   }

 \newcommand{\simplify}{%
 \cleardoublepage\ClearShipoutPictureBG
 }
```

and use it like

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

 \newcommand{\beautify}{%
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperLeft{\put(0,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}}}
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-50,-25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-50,25){\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}}}
   }
   }

 \newcommand{\simplify}{%
 \cleardoublepage\ClearShipoutPictureBG
 }


\begin{document}
\title{Magnificent title}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\beautify
\chapter{New chapter}
\lipsum[5]
\simplify
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As simple as that! :-) I did not try it at all. Thank you.

Comment: @usr203050 I have added some more. You may like that too :-)

Comment: Very good, that is exactly what I secretly wanted also! Thank you very much.